# WebStorm not recognizing HTML tags in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webstorm

I have a render method in many of my React JS project components, this is an example:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.playlists.length === 0) {
      return (
        <div>
          <NavigationBar />
          <h2>You have no Playlits yet!</h2>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <NavigationBar />
          <h1>My Playlists</h1>
      <div>
      <Card>
      <CardContent>
      <Typography>{playlist.name}</Typography>
      <Typography>Number of videos: {playlist.videos.total}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      </Card>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained" href={"/videos/" + playlist.id}>
          Show Videos
      </Button>
      <Button
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
            fontSize: "15px",
      }}
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      onClick={() => {
        deletePlaylist(playlist.id);
        clickConfirm();
      }}
    >
      Delete Playlist
      </Button>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

I'm using WebStorm IDE, and under every HTML tag such as `<div>` or `<h2>` I am getting the error `Unresolved variable or type` and under each closing tag like `</div>` I am getting the error `Expression statement is not assignment or call`. I can't understand why is this happening?

As you can see I am also getting `Unreachable code` errors

[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues here. The first one is that your tags are unbalanced. You should add one more div to the end of the expression in the first return statement and remove one last div at the end of the second return statement.

The second issue could be with the [language level](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-javascript.html). The most recent versions suggest you to change it when it is required.

[image: Invalid language level]

If you don't see this prompt, you can do it yourself like in the picture below.

[image: Configure language level manually]